# Assign an upper bound for the height of a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a tableview whose height is dynamically adjusted. The height is adjusted so that the tableview only includes a certain number of rows, and no empty rows. So, if there are only 2 rows then the height is smaller, and if there are 4 rows then the height is bigger. However, I do not want its height to go past a certain point. How can I allow the height to be dynamically adjusted, while not letting the height ever reach past a certain point?

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet var tableViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

var items: [String] = ["Swift", "Is", "So", "Amazing"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! UITableViewCell

    // Make sure the table view cell separator spans the whole width
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // Adjust the height of the tableview
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)

    // Add a border to the tableView
    tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    print("We ran ViewWillAppear")
}

// This function is used for adjusting the height of the tableview
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

// Allow cell deletion in tableview
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in
        // delete item at indexPath
        self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height - 44
        print(self.items)
        print("Number of rows: \(tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))")
    }

    delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return [delete]
}
```

Comment: You can either code the limit where you set the height constraint, say using a `max` function, or you could set a lower priority for the tableview height constraint and create other constraints that limit the height of the tableview

Comment: I tried editing the height constraint so that in Main.storyboard it is tableView.height "Less than or equal to" 352 but it throws an error. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: You are trying the right thing. what you need to look is Content Higging Priority and Content Compression Resistance Priority, which when set will remove the error and satisfy your criteria.

Comment: You would need two constraints; one that sets the height (this is the one you set in your code).  Set the priority of this constraint to 999.  Then create a <= constraint with a priority of 1000.

Comment: My first constraint is in main.storyboard, like it was before. This constraint is tableView.height "Equal" to 176, with priority 999. I added a second constraint which is that tableView.height "Less than or Equal to" 352, with priority 1000. 352 is equivalent to 8 rows in the tableView. However, it still shows 9 rows if there were 9 rows (instead of forcing the last row to not appear, which is what I want). Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `viewWillAppear` , you can try

```
let limit:CGFloat = 900.0

if tableView.contentSize.height  < limit {
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.contentSize.height)
}
else {
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: tableView.frame.origin.x, y: tableView.frame.origin.y, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: limit )
}
```

Or set value to

```
tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = ( tableView.contentSize.height < limit ) ? tableView.contentSize.height : limit

self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Will your first solution work in all cases if I have a height constraint in Main.storyboard?

Comment: yes , if you put it inside **viewDidLayoutSubviews**

Comment: Great! I solved this by using your first method above. I put what's in the first block inside the viewDidLayout Subviews function. At the same time, I had a constraint for the height of the tableView that was also modified in each of the if/else blocks of the above code. I only needed to use one constraint for the tableView.